# Relation between $f(x)$ and $f(\sqrt{x})$

Tags: functions

This might be silly, but if $f(\sqrt{x})=\frac{0.1}{a}x$, is $f(x)=\frac{0.1}{a}x^2$?

Comment: If $f(\sqrt{x})=\frac{0.1}{a}x$ holds for all $x \geq 0$, then we have $f(x)=\frac{0.1}{a}x^2$ for all $x \geq 0$ but you cannot tell anything about $f(x)$ for $x<0$.

Comment: Yes, with the restriction that $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument of a function is a *dummy variable*, meaning that it is a placeholder for a number. Consider $g(x)=x^2$; we could just as equally have written $g(y)=y^2$. *The function is about the operation performed on the argument, not the argument itself.* It might help to think of $f$ as

$$
f(\text{number})=(\text{number})^2\times\frac{0.1}{a}
$$

This makes it clearer what is going on: you take a number, you square it, and you multiply it by $\frac{0.1}{a}$. It is this kind of thinking that leads us directly to the answer:

$$
f(x)=x^2
\times\frac{0.1}{a}=\frac{x^2}{10a}$$

So remember, it is the *rule* that is the defining property of a function. The dummy variable is merely there to illustrate what happens to a number when it is inputted into the function. With this in mind, $\sqrt{x}$ seems like an odd choice. It is clearer, and less likely to cause confusion, to use something like $x$ or $y$ instead.

NB as Sangchul Lee has pointed out, the domain of the function is important: this answer assumes that $x\geq0$, as I presume you only care about real-valued functions.